# Mysql equivalent of datetime year to fraction(3) in informix

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp, informix, milliseconds

I have a table and in that table there is a column with datatype as `datetime year to fraction(3)`.

So when i am creating the same table and column in mysql will `datetime(3)` as the type give the same result.?

Also when i am inserting or updating the data in that column by the following statement

`insert into table_name (column) values (sysdate(3))`

will that be same as that of informix.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be at MySQL version 5.6.4 or later to declare columns with fractional-second time datatypes.

For example, `DATETIME(3)` will give you millisecond resolution in your timestamps, and `TIMESTAMP(6)` will give you microsecond resolution on a *nix-style timestamp.

Read this:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html

`NOW(6)` will give you the present time with microsecond precision, and `NOW(3)` will do the same with millisecond precision.

If your server gives you a bunch of different six-digit integers back when you issue this query a bunch of times, you're at a working version.

```
 SELECT MICROSECOND(CAST(NOW(6) AS DATETIME(6)))
```

If you get an error, you're not at the right version.